# Routing 4 Networks

Tags: linux, networking, debian, routing

I've been trying for almost a week to make it work but without success. I start to be hopeless.

I have 4 ethernet adapters :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:85:a9:ad:54:1e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.100.36.2/29 brd 10.100.36.7 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::3285:a9ff:fead:541e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:f3:c1:04:64:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 69.70.164.242/30 brd 69.70.164.243 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe04:6440/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:f3:c1:04:a0:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.45.13.1/24 brd 10.45.13.255 scope global eth2
    inet6 fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe04:a02f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:10:7b:c9:58:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.45.15.1/24 brd 10.45.15.255 scope global eth3
    inet6 fe80::2a10:7bff:fec9:5876/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is the default route my linux server (Debian) give me at startup :

```
69.70.164.240/30 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 69.70.164.242
10.100.36.0/29 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.100.36.2
10.45.15.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.45.15.1
10.45.13.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.45.13.1
default via 10.45.15.254 dev eth3
default via 10.45.13.254 dev eth2
default via 69.70.164.241 dev eth1
default via 10.100.36.1 dev eth0
```

Here's what I want to do. eth0 is my VDSL line and eth1 is my cable line. I want to:

- Forward all traffic from `10.45.13.0` (eth2) to the gateway `10.100.36.1` (eth0)
- Forward all traffic from `10.45.15.0` (eth3) to the gateway `69.70.164.241` (eth1)

If I make this work, I would be happy enough but I would also like to make `10.45.13.0` invisible from `10.45.15.0` and vice-versa.

Thanks you for any help in advance.

Comment: YOu have far too many 'default' routes.  You should have only one default route per route table.  Remove the others.

Answer (score 0):

here you have a clear explanation and setup for this, try it:

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html

Comment: From my understand, I have to leave as "default" the main connection I want (my VDSL) and create a table for my cable connection ?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you should only have on default route with the same metric. Reorder these using metrics, or create a multipath routes using weights of your choosing for the default route.  You still need routes, a default no less, in the main table for when your source address is unspecified (e.g., because it is not a reply and you haven't called `bind()`). See [my answer to a nearly identical question](http://serverfault.com/questions/417885/configure-gateway-for-two-nics-through-static-routeing/508710#508710). I just don't have enough rep to mark this as a duplicate.